# JavaFx: Populate ComboBox with different enums depending on another ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx, enums, combobox

I have two ComboBoxes:

```
    final ComboBox<MainCategory> comboBoxMainCategory = new ComboBox<>();
    final ComboBox<SubCategory> comboBoxSubCategory = new ComboBox<>();
```

Depending on the value chosen in comboBoxMainCategory, the comboBoxSubCategory should be populated with the corresponding enum.

```
    public enum MainCategory { // extra enum class
      EUROPE("Europe"),
      USA("USA");
    }

    public enum SubCategoryEurope { // extra enum class
      GERMANY("Germany"),
      FRANCE("France");
    }

    public enum SubCategoryUSA {
      COLORADO("Colorado"),
      CALIFORNIA("California");
    }
```

If "Europe" is chosen for comboBoxMainCategory, comboBoxSubCategory should be populated with SubCategoryEurope. If "USA", with SubCategoryUSA.

How do you achieve this?

Here's my code:

```
    final ComboBox<MainCategory> comboBoxMainCategory = new ComboBox<();
    final ComboBox<SubCategory> comboBoxSubCategory = new ComboBox<>(); 

    comboBoxMainCategory.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, 
    newValue) ->
          {
            if (newValue == null) { // newValue: Europe || USA
              comboBoxSubCategory.getItems().clear();
              comboBoxSubCategory.setDisable(true);
            } else if (newValue.equals(MainCategory.EUROPE)) {

 comboBoxSubCategory.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(SubCategoryEurope.values())); 
            comboBoxSubCategory.setDisable(false);
        } else {
             comboBoxSubCategory.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(SubCategoryUSA.values())); 
            comboBoxSubCategory.setDisable(false);}
        });
```

Problem is, because comboBoxSubCategory is "SubCategory", there is a type error if it is populated with 'SubCategoryEurope' or 'SubCategoryUSA'.

What is the best way to solve this? Sorry if it's a silly question, I'm new to JavaFx.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Europe/USA and Florida/France in the same (sub-)category? You need to cleanup your logic <g>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use enums at all, since this doesn't allow for data manipulation without recompiling. If you insist on using enums though, you need to use `Object` or a interface implemented with both subcategory enum types as parameter type for `comboBoxSubCategory`:

```
comboBoxMainCategory.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue == null) { // newValue: Europe || USA
            comboBoxSubCategory.getItems().clear();
            comboBoxSubCategory.setDisable(true);
        } else {
            comboBoxSubCategory.setDisable(false);
            List<? extends Object> list;
            switch (newValue) {
                case EUROPE:
                    list = Arrays.asList(SubCategoryEurope.values());
                    break;
                default:
                    list = Arrays.asList(SubCategoryUSA.values());
                    break;
            }
            comboBoxSubCategory.getItems().setAll(list);
        }
    });
```

---

The better approach would be using a `Map<String, List<String>>` to store the data:

```
Map<String, List<String>> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("EUROPE", Arrays.asList("GERMANY", "FRANCE"));
data.put("USA", Arrays.asList("COLORADO", "CALIFORNIA"));

comboBoxMainCategory.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        List<String> list = data.get(newValue);
        if (list != null) {
            comboBoxSubCategory.setDisable(false);
            comboBoxSubCategory.getItems().setAll(list);
        } else {
            comboBoxSubCategory.getItems().clear();
            comboBoxSubCategory.setDisable(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Even in your way enums can be written and then cached in the `Map`. (Just saying).

Comment: Yes but this doesn't solve the fundamental design flaw of not using the same type to represent the subcategories. Would you still use this kind of approach, if all countries have subcategories for regions? Would you recommend making constants for all 50 states of the USA?

Comment: I see what you mean - that's the reason I wrote 'Just saying'. There are (possibly) a tons of situations where the enums are needed. Up voting your answer... GL, friend.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Trying this right now. Unfortunately, 'List<String> list = data.get(newValue); ' ends up with "list" being null. I can't see why ...

Comment: @RuntimeError This example requires you to use the `String` keys as items for the category combo box, not your enum values...

Comment: in any reasonably well designed context, you wouldn't do any manual updating of the subCategory: instead, there would be a model that has an observableList of subCategory and the second combo would be bound to that list :) My turn of just saying ... second coffee pending <g>

Comment: Thanks, fabian, and also Basti (tried your approach, too and it worked) :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun (and to flesh out my comments): a more versatile approach than those in the other answers is to move away the focus of interest from the concrete nature of the backing data to a more general solution of the use-case at hand. The drawback of letting the UI implement special cases is always the same - you have to do it over and over again for each special UI and each special data type. The way out is always the same, too: implement a Model that takes over the general aspect and re-use that in concrete UI/data contexts.

The general aspects here are:

- there's list of items with each having a list of dependent objects (same or different type)
- this (let's call it root) list of items is shown in a control
- from root list, a single item can be chosen (aka: selected)
- another control should show the dependents of the root

The general approach is to have a Model that

- manages list of items
- has the notion of one of those items as selected (or current or active or ..)
- manages a list of dependent items that always is the dependent list of the selected item
- its state (root items, current item, dependent items) is exposed as properties

The advantages of such a Model are

- can be formally and rigorouly tested, so using code can rely on its proper functioning
- it's re-usable for any data context
- it's re-usable for many controls
- usage is pretty simple by binding

In the example below, the Model is named RelationModel which expects root items of type RelationProvider (which allows access to a list of dependents, it's one option, could just as well use f.i. a Function to build the dependents). It is used once with a plain Map of String/list and once with enums of Continents/Countries, each very simple to implement. Note that the resulting UI is blissfully unaware of the nature of the data, implemented solely against the model.

Naturally, not production grade, in particular, not formally tested and the model with just the barest functionality :)

```
public class CombosWithCategories extends Application {

    public interface RelationProvider<T> {
        default ObservableList<T> getRelations() {
            return emptyObservableList();
        };
    }

    /**
     * A model that manages a list of RelationProviders and has the notion
     * of a current relationProvider with relations (it's a kind-of selectionModel).
     * 
     * <T> the type of elements in the list of relations 
     */
    public static class RelationModel<T> {

        /**
         * all relationProviders managed by this model
         */
        private ListProperty<RelationProvider<T>> relationProviders;
        /**
         * The owner of the relations. Must be contained in the providers managed
         * by this model.
         */
        private ObjectProperty<RelationProvider<T>> relationProvider;
        private ListProperty<T> relations;

        public RelationModel() {
            initProperties();
        }

        /**
         * The RelationProviders managed by the model.
         */
        public ListProperty<RelationProvider<T>> relationProvidersProperty() {
            return relationProviders;
        }

        /**
         * The RelationProvider that manages the current relations.
         */
        public ObjectProperty<RelationProvider<T>> relationProviderProperty() {
            return relationProvider;
        }

        public RelationProvider<T> getRelationProvider() {
            return relationProviderProperty().get();
        }

        public ListProperty<T> relations() {
            return relations;
        }

        /**
         * Callback from invalidation of current relationProvider.
         * Implemented to update relations.
         */
        protected void relationProviderInvalidated() {
            RelationProvider<T> value = getRelationProvider();
            relations().set(value != null ? value.getRelations() : emptyObservableList());
        }

        /**
         * Creates and wires all properties.
         */
        private void initProperties() {
            relationProviders = new SimpleListProperty<>(this, "relationProviders", observableArrayList());
            relationProvider = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "relationProvider") {

                @Override
                protected void invalidated() {
                    // todo: don't accept providers that are not in the list
                    relationProviderInvalidated();
                }

            };
            relations = new SimpleListProperty<>(this, "relations");
            relationProviderInvalidated();

        }

    }

    /**
     * Implement the ui against a RelationModel. Here we create
     * the same UI with a model backed by enums or a Map, respectively
     */
    private Parent createContent() {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane(
                new Tab("Enums", createRelationUI(createEnumRelationModel())),
                new Tab("Manual map", createRelationUI(createMapRelationModel()))
                );

        return new BorderPane(tabPane);
    }

    /**
     * Common factory for UI: creates and returns a Parent that
     * contains two combo's configured to use the model.
     */
    protected <T> Parent createRelationUI(RelationModel<T> model) {
        ComboBox<RelationProvider<T>> providers = new ComboBox<>();
        providers.itemsProperty().bind(model.relationProvidersProperty());
        providers.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(model.relationProviderProperty());

        ComboBox<T> relations = new ComboBox<>();
        relations.itemsProperty().bind(model.relations());
        relations.valueProperty().addListener((src, ov, nv) -> {
            LOG.info("relation changed: " + nv); 
        });

        return new VBox(10, providers, relations);
    }


    // ------------- manual with maps

    /**
     * On-the-fly creation of a RelationModel using a backing map.
     */
    protected RelationModel<String> createMapRelationModel() {
        RelationModel<String> model = new RelationModel<>();
        Map<String, ObservableList<String>> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("EUROPE", observableArrayList("GERMANY", "FRANCE"));
        data.put("AMERICA", observableArrayList("MEXICO", "USA"));
        for (String key: data.keySet()) {
            model.relationProvidersProperty().add(new RelationProvider<String>() {

                @Override
                public ObservableList<String> getRelations() {
                    return data.get(key);
                }

                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    return key;
                }


            });
        }
        return model;
    }
    //-------------------- enum
    /**
     * RelationModel using Enums.
     */
    protected RelationModel<Object> createEnumRelationModel() {
        RelationModel<Object> model = new RelationModel<Object>();
        model.relationProvidersProperty().setAll(Continent.values());
        return model;
    }

    public enum EuropeanCountry {
        FRANCE, GERMANY;
    }

    public enum AmericanCountry {
        MEXICO, CANADA, USA;
    }

    public enum Continent implements RelationProvider<Object> {
        AMERICA(AmericanCountry.values()),
        EUROPE(EuropeanCountry.values())
        ;

        ObservableList<Object> subs;
        private Continent(Object[] subs) {
            this.subs = FXCollections.observableArrayList(subs);
        }
        @Override
        public ObservableList<Object> getRelations() {
            return FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList(subs);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.setTitle(FXUtils.version());
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(CombosWithCategories.class.getName());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a generic placeholder interface

```
public interface EnumPlaceHolder<E extends Enum<?>> {

  public abstract String getDisplayValue();

  public abstract E getEnum();

}
```

Create an implementation for all your enums. For example

```
public class EuropePlaceholder implements EnumPlaceHolder<Europe> {

  private final Europe value;

  public EuropePlaceholder(Europe pValue){
     value = pValue;
  }

  @Override
  public String getDisplayValue() {
    // here you create a user-friendly version of your enum for display
    return value.toString();
  }

  @Override
  public Europe getEnum() {
    return value;
  }

}
```

Then change the type of your `ComboBox<Enum>` to `ComboBox<EnumPlaceholder<?>>` and you can add any of your implemented `EnumPlaceholders` to it. When retrieving the selected item you can check which one is contained via instance check

```
EnumPlaceholder<?> selectedItem = ...;
if(selectedItem instanceof EuropePlaceholder){
   Europe selectedEuropeEnum = (Europe) selectedItem.getEnum();
} else if(....){
  // check with else if for your other enums
}
```

And to display your enum in your combobox you call the `getDisplayValue()` of the EnumPlaceholder and show the returned `String` in your cell :)

**EDIT**
Tho in general i have to agree with fabians answer. You shouldn't use enums for a construct like this. Rather use a Map<> or a List<> with appropriate content and structure.

Comment: @fabian thanks, edited it. Didn't think of that and didn't run the code through a compiler or an ide either :o mb